Invalid session EUnQ7_jkg_pu1UqSAAAE (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
I am facing this error message in my websocket server application.
The server has 2 main tasks. One of them contuniously listens to an SQS queue, and the other one gets some data from redis and updates it.
Below you can see how I handle the tasks.
def start_server():
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)


async def run_tasks():
    await asyncio.gather(
        update_redis_data(),
        handle_sqs_messages(),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
    server_thread.start()
    asyncio.run(run_tasks())


